# Regex: Find/Select all files that do not contain the words

Tags: windows, regex

I want to search and find all .html files that do not contain the words: "Use API site scope"

I try this,  `(?!>)(Use API site scope).*` but I believe it must be another negative looke ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer:

`(?s)\A(?!.*(Use API site scope).*$)`

or

`(?s)\A((?!Use API site scope).)+\z`

or

`(?s)\A(?!.*?(?<!\w)(Use API site scope)(?!\w)).*`